# Programatically Block Site C# Without Hosts File

Tags: c#

My goal is to block access to a certain site without modifying the host file. You can do that manually by going to Internet Properties - > Security - > Restricted Sites - > Add. (as shown here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbe4.jpg) However, I cannot seem to find a way to do this with code.

Is there any way to emulate this process in c#?

Comment: Hint: They are stored in registry.

Comment: You sure? I added a site as a test, then searched the site's name in the registry and had zero results.

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I found out why

Comment: You could also go the heavy route and do some P/Invoke with [WinDivert](https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) (:

Comment: Ehhh, I think I found a much easier way. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
            RegistryKey r = (Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains"));
            r.CreateSubKey("example.com");
            RegistryKey x = (Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\skype.com"));
            x.CreateSubKey("subdomain");
            RegistryKey z = (Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\skype.com\apps"));
            z.SetValue("https", 4);
```